# Is is safe to parse the Abstract Syntax Trees of untrusted code?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it ok to use the [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module to parse and modify untrusted external Python code programatically?

I will just parse the source code, get some info from the source code (docstrings, function definitions, maybe, I don't know) and leave it there, not compile it or run it.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but for the purpose of parsing and _modifying_ source-code into other source-code, a CST (concrete syntax tree) is more suitable than an AST (abstract syntax tree) as you can preserve formatting and comments. There is also a compromise between the two: https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why_libcst.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `ast.parse` function then it should be safe. As the documentation says,  this function will

> Parse the source into an AST node. Equivalent to compile(source, filename, mode, ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)

which simply parses the file even if it contains invalid Python code. It doesn't do any sort of evaluation.

If your aim is to evaluate expressions, then you can use `ast.literal_eval`, which is safer than the built-in `eval` statement

Answer (score 3):

"Unsafe" implies something bad could happen controlled by the artifact you are engaging.   Since parsing only builds ASTs, and (assuming there isn't something malicious in the parsing and AST building code), then parsing an arbitrary bit of text can't hurt you.

Typically to get malicious behaviour from the outside, something (controlled by *you*) must essentially execute some supplied code.   Clearly building a parse tree doesn't execute the outside program.   However, if you built an interpreter that interpreted the parse tree and ran it, you might have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe so. No code is executed. In fact, parsing the ast is exactly what `ast.literal_eval` does, and that's deemed safe.